# Problems when trying to read a file and add its values to a JFrame

Tags: java, swt

I'm getting this error when trying to add some values from file archives :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
```

This is my code:

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    while (br.ready()) {

        line = br.readLine();
        st = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");

        JTable table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(new Object[0][], new String[] { "TEST", "TEST2","TEST3"}));
        chargeTable = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();

        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            rowData.add(st.nextElement());
        }

        if (!rowData.isEmpty()) {
            tabelaCarregada.addRow(rowData);
            rowData.clear();
        }

    }

    br.close();
    fr.close();

    JFrame jd; 
    jd = new Tabela(chargeTable);
    jd.pack();
    jd.setVisible(true);
```

I'm only reading a file, then I'm trying to add every line from the file to a table and put it in a JFrame.

Inside the file is like that:

example1|example2|example3

example1|example2|example3

example1|example2|example3

example1|example2|example3

example1|example2|example3

What I'm doing wrong? This error is confusing for me.

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

```
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(arq);

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String line;
    StringTokenizer st;
    Vector<Object> rowData = new Vector<Object>();

    chargeTable = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[0][], new String[] {"Teste1", "Teste2"});

    while (br.ready()) {
        line = br.readLine();
        st = new StringTokenizer(line, "|");

        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            rowData.add(st.nextElement());
        }

        if (!rowData.isEmpty()) {
            chargeTable.addRow(rowData);
            rowData.clear();
        }

    }

    JTable table = new JTable();
    table.setModel(chargeTable);

    br.close();
    fr.close();

    JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane();
    sp.add(table);

    JFrame jd = new JFrame(); 
    jd.add(sp);
    jd.pack();
    jd.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Why does this have both [tag:Swing] and [tag:SWT] tags added?  They are two GUI toolkits that should not be mixed together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should create a DefaultTableModel before you start reading your data (ie. outside of the while loop). The model will only contain the column names.
2. Then for every line of data you read from the file you create a Vector and add each token from the tokenizer to the Vector.
3. Then you add the Vector to the DefaultTableModel
4. When you finish processing all line of data in the file you create the JTable using the DefaultTableModel.
5. You add the JTable to a JScrollPane and add the scrollpane to the frame.

Edit:

1. There is a constructor for just specifying the column names (with a 0 row count).
2. You need to create a new row Vector for every row that you add to the model.
3. Don't use the clear() method since that will remove the data you just added.
4. You can't add the table to the scrollpane. You add the table to the viewport of the scrollpane. The easiest way to do this is when you create the scrollpane. `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just made an update at my question, trying to follow your tips. But it didn't work. Even the column names are not appearing, maybe the problem is when creating the DefaultTableModel?